# SVM with SKLearn & OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, scikit-learn, svm

I am trying to predict the emotion shown on the image using SVM. However when i run my code i get a warning as below and my prediction is not shown:

**DeprecationWarning: Passing 1d arrays as data is deprecated in 0.17 and willraise ValueError in 0.19. Reshape your data either using X.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or X.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
  DeprecationWarning)**

here is the code for training and testing:

```
    emotions = ["anger", "neutral"]
    def make_sets(emotions):
    training_data = []
    training_labels = []

    for emotion in emotions:
        training = glob.glob("try here\\%s\\*" %emotion)
        for item in training:
            image = cv2.imread(item) 
            gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            training_data.append(gray.ravel())
            training_labels.append(emotions.index(emotion))
    return training_data, training_labels

    x,y = make_sets(emotions)
    new_x = np.asarray(x)
new_x.flatten()
new_y = np.asarray(y)
clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=1.0)
clf.fit(new_x,new_y)
new_image = cv2.imread('test.jpg')
gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(new_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
clf.predict(gray_img.ravel())
```

Comment: It's just a warning, not an error. You should get your output though

Comment: Sklearn tells you exactly what you need to do and as this is a warning, no output at all is changed by that warning. If you are not in some interactive shell like jupyter/ipython, then of course there is no output without a print-command.

Comment: This is not just a warning ... it says **ValueError **...  I would check shape of `new_x` and `new_y`... If anyone of them is 1D array then make it  `new_x.reshape(-1, 1)`